# Remove all rows in GTK_COMBO_BOX (GTK_TREE_STORE)

Tags: gtk

I want to remove all rows from combobox, I tried this but remain one row:

```
GtkTreeModel *model;
GtkTreeIter iter;   

model = gtk_combo_box_get_model(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo));
if (gtk_tree_model_get_iter_first(model, &iter)) {
    do {
        gtk_tree_store_remove(GTK_TREE_STORE(model), &iter);
    } while (gtk_tree_model_iter_next(model, &iter));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `gtk_tree_store_remove()` documentation you can see that `gtk_tree_model_iter_next()` is not required in your code -- you should just check that iter is still valid. Alternatively you can just use `gtk_tree_store_clear()`.